# Shell script errors

Tags: grass-gis, ubuntu, shell

So I am working with shell script on Ubuntu Linux and I'm trying to create a script that calculates the ndvi of 2 rasters using Grass GIS, but that is not the problem. The problem is that every time I am trying to execute a command I get an error like this `line 52: g.list: command not found` and I have used this link (https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Compile_and_Install_Ubuntu) to install Grass, is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Are you running the script *in a GRASS session* ??

Comment: No, maybe I forgot to start GRASS from a command. Is there a special Shell command, or is it just `start Grass` ?

Comment: Yes, type "grass72" into a terminal window

Comment: I did with grass70 and it launches, as it should, but I can't seem to execute my shell, maybe I haven't used my directories correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the trick here was to set the paths right and because I wanted my script to work on multiple machines I added the followed lines:

```
echo -n "Enter Grass program directory (i.e /usr/lib/grass70):"
read GRASS_P
export GISBASE=$GRASS_P

echo -n "Enter the number of your GRASS version (i.e 70):"
read version
export GRASS_VERSION=$version
```

and I did this for every directory.

And so I placed my inputs in strings and then I set my paths based on those inputs.

If what I did was wrong feel free to correct me, but it worked for my situation.

Comment: Please also check this convenient batch job possibility: https://grass.osgeo.org/grass72/manuals/grass7.html#batch-jobs-with-the-exec-interface